# A list of functions

Tags: functional-programming, lisp, scheme

Is there a way to make a list that holds functions? What I'm trying to do is, make a list of some arithmetic operators  `(+ - * /)` so I can easily manipulate their order and apply them to a list of numbers.

So, if I have that list, I'd use it like this:

```
(apply (map (lambda (x)
              x)
            '(+ - * /))
       '(1 2 3 4))
```

I'm a novice programmer, so if there's a better way to do such operation, your advice is much appreciated.

Comment: Ammar: By hand, expand-out and show what the code would do that you wrote. Next, do the same thing with your new code. You should see the difference.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Lists are made with the function LIST.

```
(list 1 2 3)

(list + - * /)
```

Applying a list of symbols makes no sense:

```
(apply (map (lambda (x) x) '(+ - * /)) '(1 2 3 4))
```

Would be (applying a list of functions still makes no sense):

```
(apply (map (lambda (x) x) (list + - * /)) '(1 2 3 4))
```

Simplified (still wrong):

```
(apply (list + - * /) '(1 2 3 4))
```

But, maybe you wanted this:

```
(map (lambda (f)
       (apply f '(1 2 3 4)))
     (list + - * /))
```

In Common Lisp:

```
(mapcar #'(lambda (f)
            (apply f '(1 2 3 4)))
        (list #'+ #'- #'* #'/))
```

Returns:

```
(10 -8 24 1/24)
```

Comment: What I want is to return the result from applying these functions in that order to the list, (+ 1 (- 2 (* 3 4))), (ignore the extra element in the function list).

Comment: Thanks for pointing the (list #'+ #'- #'* #'/), it lead me to what I wanted.

Answer (score 2):

I'm surprised no one has mentioned [quasiquotation](http://docs.plt-scheme.org/reference/quasiquote.html). :-) In Scheme, you could say:

```
`(,+ ,- ,* ,/)
```

or in Common Lisp:

```
`(,#'+ ,#'- ,#'* ,#'/)
```

In some cases, especially involving complex lists, quasiquotation makes the code much simpler to read than the corresponding `list` version.